# The groupby function didn't work on two dimensional array in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, group-by, laravel-query-builder

```
id  p_id    approve m_approve
1   75       1       0
2   74       1       1
3   73       1       1
4   72       1       1
5   75       1       1
6   73       0       1
7   71       1       0
8   70       1       1
9   69       0       1
10  75       0       0
11  75       0       0
12  75       0       0
13  75       1       0
14  75       1       0
15  75       0       1


  $result = DB::table('a16s_likes')
   ->select ('id','p_id','approve','m_approve')
   ->get()    ///become collection
   ->groupBy('p_id')
   ->toarray(); //->all()
   echo '<pre>' ;
   print_r($result);
```

I got the right one dimentional array
[image]
But when I use

```
->groupBy('p_id','approve')
->all();
```

I got the same one dimensional array result?
[image]
not got the two dimentional array?

How can I get p_id(75)-approve(0) and p_id(75)-approve(1)  two group and just take last 2 rows?

I fix the code

```
->groupBy(['p_id','m_approve'])
```

got
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby)

> Multiple grouping criteria may be passed as an array. Each array element will be applied to the corresponding level within a multi-dimensional array

Which means that your code must be `->groupBy(['p_id','approve'])`

Comment: Thanks I forgot that! But it still not work. I screen capture the result above!